# Input Number Range Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was wondering if it makes sense to write this react component from scratch or should I be using a library? I searched for some libraries but I couldn't find a library that I could really customize. I was really thinking of just trying to write this from scratch, but I was concerned about edge cases that might not be obvious until I start coding so I was hoping to find a library. Like ally as an example.

Here is an image of it.

Thank you all in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is "ally"?

Comment: Looks pretty niche with the font/colour choices. Depends how anal your design team are. I'd probably build it custom since my team are quite particular

Comment: I was thinking of building it myself. Is there any tutorials that might help me out with the mouse scrolling?